# Android: Curve drawing animation

Tags: android, animation, draw, curve

I can draw a curve (e.g. cubic bezier) using Path class and on the other hand I can animate whole View, but is there any help from android 2.x framework when I want to animate a curve drawing?

Comment: maybe this help you : http://nineoldandroids.com/